# Touchscreen not working properly

Tags: suspend, touchscreen, inspiron, elantech

My touchscreen intermittently works on my Dell Inspiron 7537, mostly not. It generally is not detected on bootup, but only when the computer resumes after suspend.

When it is detected (after suspend) lsusb produces:

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 04f3:0201 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
```

Here's output from dmesg that might be helpful, i'm not sure what it means:

```
[12066.321322] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[12066.529353] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[12066.737096] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 64, error -71
[12066.737157] usb usb2-port7: unable to enumerate USB device                                                                                                                                
[12072.921194] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 65 using xhci_hcd
[12078.238349] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=0201
[12078.238353] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
[12078.238355] usb 2-7: Product: Touchscreen
[12078.238357] usb 2-7: Manufacturer: ELAN
[12078.248271] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/0003:04F3:0201.0007/input/input39
[12078.248764] hid-multitouch 0003:04F3:0201.0007: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [ELAN Touchscreen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0
[12206.688765] usb 2-7: reset full-speed USB device number 65 using xhci_hcd
[12211.988422] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[12212.216526] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[12212.444408] usb 2-7: reset full-speed USB device number 65 using xhci_hcd
[12212.564453] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[12212.792460] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[12213.020418] usb 2-7: reset full-speed USB device number 65 using xhci_hcd
[12213.020619] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[12213.228624] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[12213.436379] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 65, error -71
[12213.556394] usb 2-7: reset full-speed USB device number 65 using xhci_hcd
[12213.556582] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[12213.764606] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[12213.972420] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 65, error -71
[12213.972501] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 65
[12214.292362] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 66 using xhci_hcd
[12214.412382] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[12214.644405] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[12214.872380] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 67 using xhci_hcd
[12214.992373] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[12215.220398] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[12215.448371] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 68 using xhci_hcd
[12215.448579] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[12215.656548] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[12215.864407] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 68, error -71
[12215.984466] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 69 using xhci_hcd
[12215.984740] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[12216.192737] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[12216.400385] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 69, error -71
[12216.400432] usb usb2-port7: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Booting from a LiveUSB, the touchscreen works out of the box on Ubuntu Gnome, Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS, but not on Ubuntu 17.10, KDE Neon (any version the last couple of years) or Kubuntu. I've been having this problem for a few years now i've searched for answers on here and other websites but to no avail. Is there anyone out there who could help?

Comment: Several (offsite) posts suggest that perhaps this is a power issue - do you have other things plugged into your USB ports?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the first reply i've ever gotten for this on many sites.  No, having things plugged in or not has any effect on it being detected.  Problem still persists ...

Comment: That may be because the problem *seems like* a marginal hardware issue - can you try to disable USB 3 (force using USB 2) and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Hi there again after such a long time.

After much rooting around, I can't seem to figure out how to downgrade  or disable USB 3, have you any suggestions?  I'm fairly sure I can't do it through BIOS either.

I'm no expert with dmesg, but from what i can see the system is constantly trying to connect the touchscreen, but mostly failing:
  
`usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71`  

then the odd time it succeeds, then a few minutes or seconds later, resets itself and its gone again:

`usb 2-7: reset full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd`

Comment: It has been a while - I don't have much help for you on this, but I did google [this suggestion](https://www.systutorials.com/241533/how-to-force-a-usb-3-0-port-to-work-in-usb-2-0-mode-in-linux/)

Comment: I came across that link you sent alright, just need to figure out how to reverse it.  Thanks so much for your help, like i said literally noone else has responded to this question on numerous forums, so your help was very much appreciated. will keep you updated if i find a solution